# Upgrade/migrate GeoServer configuration (workspace XML)

Tags: geoserver, migration

I would like to upgrade my GeoServer data directory (containing XML files for workspaces, datastores, layers etc) from 2.18 to 2.21 or the current version.

I think I need to upgrade step-by-step (so, 2.19, 2.20, 2.21, 2.22, 2.23) by replacing the GeoServer binaries (webapp, docker image, etc..). But since I'm running in all kinds of issues, I thought maybe it is also possible to upgrade directly to the target version.

Is it possible to upgrade in one big step from 2.18 to 2.21 or further?

Comment: I've seen bigger step changes work, so go for it - tbh you shouldn't run into any issues going step by step either so it sounds like your set up has issues already.